# Fetch attributes from a distant relation in Core Data using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to add attributes from a distant relation of my fetched data to a UITableView - in this example it is an image of a game that is part of a match. My CoreData model includes the following relationship:

Matches <<----> Games <<-----> Images

[Entity relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntwTl.png)

I am trying to build a UITableView for Matches data and can fetch the data for the 'Matches' entity fine. For each cell in the table though I want to be able to show the related game image. This is linked to Matches via the Games entity which is linked to the Images entity.

I cannot get this image to pull through as cannot find what syntax i should be using to go though the relationships in Swift. From what I have found it appears that I shouldn't need to do another fetch request using a predicate and that the value should be accessible from the fetched Matched object (but I may be wrong). Any advice greatly appreciated.

To summarise, how do I fetch the attribute 'image' from the Images entity for each Match in my table?

Comment: Just `match.game.gameImage` ...

Comment: to get the value of match title in my table i use `let matchName : String = matchData[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "title") as! String`. How would i use `match.game.gameImage` in the same kind of way to pull the key "image" from that entity? thanks.

Comment: It should be just `let image = matchData[indexPath.row].game.gameImage` , and your code can be simplified to `let matchName = matchData[indexPath.row].title` – assuming that there are generated managed object subclasses for all entities.

Comment: ok - i think that might be the problem then as I am getting an error saying that the `NSManagedObject` has no member called 'game'. Thank you for your help - i'll need to look into managed object subclasses!!

Comment: I think subclassing my entities will be a good move and will aim to do this. Can what I was hoping to do be achieved without subclasses? Or is the lack of subclasses why I am getting the error: the `NSManagedObject` has no member called 'game'.

Comment: `matchData[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "game.gameImage")` is the (less preferable) alternative.

Comment: thanks a lot Martin. got it working with that.